# Reports tab not shown in teamcity build

Tags: maven, teamcity, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to add a sure-fire report tab in my each build. I followed the instructions given on the page https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Including+Third-Party+Reports+in+the+Build+Results#IncludingThird-PartyReportsintheBuildResults-9.1

but it does not shows up on the build page, i have restarted the teamcity server as well, i am doing this on my local windows machine.

the build is seen like this

[image]

reporting tab settings
[image]

Can anyone please help me on what am i missing here ??

Comment: did it create the files in the site directory? the path might be wrong (target/site/index.html?). Did you create the site in the build? And do you need that at all? since there is the tests tab that will show the surefire reports already automatically using the xml results created during the test phase of maven.

Comment: this i just a poc to verify if a tab is created for reporting or not, for given html. In actuals spock reports are to be displayed after each buid and yes index.html file is generated at target/site/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this working, by adding artifacts to build configuration something like this

[image]

then in reports tab adding zip!filename

[image]